# Issue with sending JSON payload using wp_remote_post()

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

I am trying to send a JSON payload to an endpoint using wp_remote_post()

Payload:

```
$body = [
 'stock_data'     => [
'post_title'  => $title,
'post_content' => $content,
'post_date' => $postdate,
'post_category' => $categoryname
]];
```

But this is what shows up at the endpoint:

```
stock_data: [object Object]
```

however, the following works:

```
$body = [
    'post_title'  => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_date' => $postdate,
    'post_category' => $categoryname
];
```

and the payload is delivered correctly.

this is how I am sending the payload:

```
$body = wp_json_encode( $body ); 

$options = [
        'body'        => $body,
        'headers'     => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'timeout'     => 60,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'blocking'    => true,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'sslverify'   => false,
        'data_format' => 'body',
    ];
    
    wp_remote_post( $endpoint, $options );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `stock_data` supposed to be an array or what?

Comment: I am trying to deliver the following JSON

{
"stock_data":{
   "post_title":"title",
   "post_content":"content",

   "post_date":"timestamp",
   "post_category":"category"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, the correct PHP array would look like this

```
$body = array (
  'stock_data' => 
  array (
    'post_title'    => 'title',
    'post_content'  => 'content',
    'post_date'     => 'timestamp',
    'post_category' => 'category',
  ),
)
```

Comment: this did the trick, thank you

Comment: Other than using the "old" array syntax, I don't see what is supposed to be different here, from the payload shown at the beginning of the question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the body of your post is expected to be a single instance of that array with member names `'post_title'`, `'post_content', and the others).

In other words it looks like it wants you to deliver this, with no `'stock_data'` subarray.

```json
{ "post_title":"title",
  "post_content":"content",
  "post_date":"timestamp",
  "post_category":"category"
}
```

That's what you deliver in the instance where it works.

You should check the docs for the endpoint you use.